# Missing `this` in typescript arrow function?

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescript class that is using the Web Audio API. I have this in a class method:

```
getTracks.filter(
    (track) => track.kind === 'audio'
).forEach(
    (track, index) => {
        if (!this._recordingData.hasOwnProperty('track information')) {
            ...
        }
    }
)
```

In the "if" statement `this` is not defined.  I am using an "arrow function".  I have tried using `.bind(this)` with the same result, as in:

```
getTracks.filter(
    (track) => track.kind === 'audio'
).forEach(
    function(track, index) {
        ...
    }.bind(this)
)
```

I saw another post that suggested the arrow function style but adding `this` as an additional argument as in:

```
getTracks.filter(
    (track) => track.kind === 'audio'
).forEach(
    (track, index) => {
        ...
    }, this
)
```

I have also tried the above after unchaining the `filter()` and `forEach()` with the same resilts, a la:

```
let foo = getTracks.filter(
    (track) => track.kind === 'audio'
)

foo.forEach(
    (track, index) => {
        ...
    }
)

-or-

foo.forEach(
    function(track, index) {
        ...
    }.bind(this)
)
```

I don't know if it matters but my tsconfig.json fill looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
        "es2018",
        "dom"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "my_app/static/js/AudioControls.ts"
  ],
}
```

it must be trivial but I am not seeing it.  Ideas?

**EDIT**

It is not an answer but I created an object local to the class method and was able to access that instead.

```
let recordingData = {}

getTracks.filter(
    (track) => track.kind === 'audio'
).forEach(
    (track, index) => {
        if (!recordingData.hasOwnProperty('track information')) {
            ...
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: The problem is not in your posted code. How is this code included in your class? And how are you calling it? Both those things could affect the value of `this` here.

Comment: It's being called from within an event listener after recording has stopped. I only have this phone at the moment. It will be a while before I can expand the code fragment.